# SQLite select query for returning records which match current day and month

Tags: sqlite

Need a SQLite query to return records which match with the current day and month only. Tried using strftime function but it gives an error... something like strftime doesnt exist.  "Select * FROM EventDetails WHERE strftime('%d',evedate) =" + currentDay + " AND strftime('%m',evedate)=" + currentMonth... EventDetails is my table, evedate is the DateTime field . CurrentDay and Currentmonth contains the day and month respectively.

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting? Also, what version of SQLite do you use? strftime is not standard SQL, but it is supposed to work in SQLite.

Comment: I am using it in xamarin ios.. I have added the package sqlite-net. Initially it was giving strftime is not a function   sort of error. Now its not giving any error but doesnt return anything